# javascript / jQuery: most efficient way to search in and update an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, performance

I am currently working on a private side/fun-project which is a small browser-game based on `javascript` and `jQuery`.

for this game i am saving data to an array of objects:

```
this.map.push(
    { 
        "id" : id, 
        "x" : pos_x,
        "y" : pos_y
    }
);
```

now i need to find and/or update data in this array quite frequently (in "real time").

for example when i need to find the array-index at a position of my coords-system, i am using `jQuery`'s `$.each()` function:

```
this.getIndexAtPos = function(x, y)
{
    var index = false;
    $.each(this.map, function(key, obj){
        if(obj.x == x && obj.y == y)
        {
            index = key;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return index;
}
```

and another example: when i need to update data for an object with a specific id, i am using `jQuery`'s `$.map()` function:

```
this.updateCoordsById = function(id, x, y)
{
    this.map = $.map(this.map, function(obj, i)
    {
        if(obj.id == id)
        {
            //only update x, y!
            obj.x = x;
            obj.y = y;
            return obj;
        }
        else
        {
            return obj;
        }
    });
}
```

it's all working fine for me so far, but i am on a rather fast computer and as the game is extending there will be more and more of these actions. like let's say a couple of hundred `$.each` and `$.map` calls per second.
that's why i am worried about performance issues, specially on slower computers.

**MY QUESTIONS:**
i know that `$.each` and `$.map` are (partly or fully) iterating my array on each call. that's why i used `return false;` inside my `$.each` function as soon as the entry is found to speed up things a little.

**1.** can i improve the performance by using other `jQuery` functions or changing the way i use them?
**2.** are there better ways (performance wise) to solve this by using native `javascript`?

**3.** should i use other datatypes/structures to boost performance?

***note:*** the procedures i need to implement always are quite similar: find objects in the array by coords(x, y); find them by id; update objects by coords(x, y); update objects by id, and so on.

i would appreciate any help, opinions and suggestions!

Comment: I think this come down the structure of your data more than the functions you are using to access it. Am I correct in assuming that your map is (hopefully rectangular) grid _i_ wide and _j_ high, and there can only one object at (x,y) at any moment?

Comment: @Rhumborl yeah, that's right.

Comment: 1 - no. 2 - yes (native JS is always faster than jQuery). 3 - yes, definitely. Can you think of any?

Comment: @Bergi i love "no / yes" answers, they are so constructive.

Comment: @Bergi 3 - i was thinking of using objects only - an object of objects. but tbh i have no idea how to implement "add"-, "search"- and "update"- functions for it. and i don't even know if it could be performing better.

Comment: Yes, a twodimensional array of the objects for efficient by-position lookup and an object that maps ids to the object for efficient by-id lookup will do much better. Try it!

Comment: @Bergi - ok thanks - so saving more data to get better perfomance, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK as this is a grid it makes sense to store it as a grid in memory.
A 2-dimensional array will give you much faster access than a one-dimensional one, and also lets you access object directly by their coordinates instead of checking the coordinates of each object.

You can also have an container object which contains all your objects, with their ID as the property, which gives you fast lookup by ID.

You can put these together by storing the ID of the object in the grid, then looking up the object in the container by the ID.

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/d75zkvnb/1/ which shows a simple example of this. The structure of the Map object is below:

```
var Map = {
    init: function(){
        this.Width = 10;
        this.Height = 10;

        // grid stores the coordinates and the IDs of the object at that coordinate
        // note this is stored by y then x.
        this.grid = [];
        // stored the actual objects, indexed by id
        this.objects = {};

        // set up the grid        
        for(var y = 0; y < this.Height; ++y)
        {
            this.grid.push(new Array(this.Width));
        }    
    },

    // gets the object at (x, y)
    GetAtCoord: function(x, y)
    {
        // find the id
        var id = this.grid[y][x];
        // directly access it from the array
        return this.objects[id];
    },

    // gets the object with the ID
    GetById: function(objId)
    {
        // direct access to the object
        return this.objects[objId];
    },

    // add an object at its stored coordinates
    AddObject: function(obj){
        this.grid[obj.y][obj.x] = obj.id;
        this.objects[obj.id] = obj;
    },

    // Move an object in the grid
    MoveObject: function(objId, newX, newY)
    {
        // get the objct to move
        var theObj = this.objects[objId];
        // reove it from the grid
        this.grid[theObj.y][theObj.x] = null;
        // updates its stored position
        theObj.x = newX;
        theObj.y = newY;

        // add it back to the grid
        this.grid[newY][newX] = objId;
    }
};
```

Comment: wow, many thanks for your effort! - i will try this. plus i also wondered bout the `-1`

Comment: it depends how you want to store the coords in your actual objects. arrays start at 0, but some coordinate system start at 1, so you have to adjust. If you are ok with storing them 0-based in your object, then just take out the -1s.

Comment: just found the reason for your `-1`: `for(var y = 0; y < this.Height; ++y )`. if you change it to `y++`, you don't need the `-1`

Comment: @Rhumborl well, nearly everything starts at `0` besides arrays in MS Access :D

Comment: another question to your code: i guess there is no way to inherit from or extend `Map` in this way - or is there?